# Date Validation with specific formats in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I want my date field to have a validation, that only accepted formats are allowed e.g

```
const ACCEPTED_DATE_FORMATS = [
  'MM/DD/YYYY', 'M/D/YYYY', 'MM/D/YYYY', 'M/DD/YYYY',
  'MM/DD/YY', 'M/D/YY', 'MM/D/YY', 'M/DD/YY',
  'DD.MM.YYYY', 'D.M.YYYY', 'D.MM.YYYY', 'DD.M.YYYY',
  'DD.MM.YY', 'D.M.YY', 'D.MM.YY', 'DD.M.YY'];
```

This is my date form

```
  dateForm = new FormGroup({
    startDate: new FormControl(''),
    endDate: new FormControl('')
  });
```

How can I do it with Validation? I am not familiar with Regex...
`Validators.Required` and `type="date"` is not what I wanted.

Does Angular have a special Validator for that or do I have to write a custom validator?

I figured out for American Date the regex would be:

`(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{4}`

EDIT:

`/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/`

accepts YYYY/MM/DD and DD/MM/YYYY.

For the other accepted formats I need your help

Answer (score -1):

you have a couple of options

- if you are using a reactive form

  - you can use the built-in regex validator
  - `startDate: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*') )`

    - insert your custom pattern to what you need
    - in your case, since you have multiple patterns your regex pattern would bee something  like

      - `^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{1}\/\d{1}\/\d{4}$`
      - I only added the first two of your patterns here. you can add more as you need them
  - or create a custom validator if you wish to apply more complex logic.

    - The Angular documentation provide a good guide for [Creating Custom Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators). if you need something more complex
- if you are using a template form

  - use the pattern attribute on the input
  - i.e. `<input name="firstName" ngModel pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">`